# String input automatically entered into readonly field

Tags: javascript, readonly

Is it possible to copy an input from a previously entered field into another uneditable field javascript? Say for example you have two name fields, the first field you must enter your name, once entered the name will automatically be copied in the second text field which is uneditable. I have done a bit of searching around but i can't seem to find anything of use for this specific situation and i'm quite knew to javascript so any sort of help or a nudge in the right direction would be great.

Comment: What do you mean "uneditable"? As in, it has a `readonly` attribute? Get the elements by `id` and get/set the appropriate `value` property of them

Comment: If you have 2 id's , one for each text field , you can do document.getElementById('inputone').value = document.getElementById('inputtwo').value

Comment: It's possible. And easy with jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WFvU9/

Comment: @Ian yes! sorry readonly is the word im looking for.

Comment: @j08691 that seems to work fine in jsfiddle but when i try to add it to my own code it doesn't work, should be between something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `keyup` listener of your input:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" readonly='readonly' />

var $input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
var $input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
$input1.addEventListener('keyup', function()
{
  $input2.value = $input1.value;
});
```

here's example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw96Q/)

Comment: It works find in jsfiddle but when i try it in my own code it doesn't work, should it be add between something?

Comment: oh wait i got it working, just added window.onload = function(event), thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could, just do the follow:

```
document.getElementById('non_editable_name').value = document.getElementById('editable_name').value;
```

if you use jquery, you can do:

```
$('#non_editable_name').val($('#editable_name').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XhZd9/). You can do this by using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#nameInput').change(function () {
        $('#secondInput').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

with:

```
<input id="nameInput" type="text"/><br />
<input id="secondInput" type="text" readonly/>
```

Comment: You're assuming the OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="entry" />
<input type="hidden" id="storage" />
```

JS

```
(function() {

    $('#entry').on('change', function() { $('#storage').val(this.value); });

})();
```

Comment: Assuming that the OP is using `jQuery`. Also , what's the point of a 'hidden` input field?

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
      <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
      <title></title>
      <script>
      function copianome(nome){
        document.getElementById('ds_name_result').value = nome;
      }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <input type="text" id="ds_name" onkeyup="copianome(this.value)" /><br />
        <input type="text" id="ds_name_result" readonly="readonly" />
      </body>
    </html>
```